# Qt. Problem with the QFileDialog: setDirectory() and directory()

Tags: qt, filedialog

I have a problem with the QFileDialog class, namely with the setDirectory() and directory() methods. I need to make it so that after opening a file, my program remembers the directory in which the selected file is stored, and the next time QFileDialog is called, it automatically opens the directory that was used last. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
static QString _st_doc_last_directory;

void MainWindow::open()
{   
    if (!fileDialog)
    
    {   fileDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
    }
    
    if (!_st_doc_last_directory.isEmpty()) fileDialog->setDirectory(_st_doc_last_directory);
    
QString fileName = fileDialog->getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Document"), ".", tr("Compressed CAD Models (*.data)"));   
    
if (!fileName.isEmpty())

    {   _st_doc_last_directory = fileDialog->directory().dirName();
    }
}
```

The crux of my problem is that when the setDirectory() or directory() method is called, my program crashes with a

> "Segmentation fault"

message. How can I fix it, please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start this method, you have this as the start window: `"."`. (admittedly I don't know what's going on internally, but I think this leads to this problem).
You can query beforehand whether your defined string is empty. if so you set a path, otherwise you store one in your string. If you don't want to do this from the beginning every time you start the program, you can also use QSettings. This saves you the path in the registry (ie if you use windows).
With `QFileInfo` you can easily get the path

```
void MainWindow::open()
{
    if(_st_doc_last_directory.isEmpty())
        _st_doc_last_directory = QDir::homePath();

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Document"), _st_doc_last_directory, tr("Compressed CAD Models (*.data)"));
    QFileInfo info(fileName);

    if(!fileName.isEmpty())        
        _st_doc_last_directory = info.absolutePath();

}
```